# How powerful was the Gaia collective mind in Foundation's Edge?

Tags: foundation

In *Foundation's Edge*, a planet called Gaia is inhabited solely by Mentalics, telepathic beings whose minds are linked together into a vast collective mind. The collective mind calls itself Gaia and includes every organism and inanimate object on the planet.

It has these known powers.

- It can sense the thoughts of non-Gaian humans.
- It can adjust the thoughts and memories of non-Gaian humans, even when those humans are hundreds of kilometers away in orbit above Gaia.
- Every human within Gaia can access deep Gaian memories from hundreds of years ago.
- It can adjust the physical climate of the Gaian world so that humans live in comfort.
- When a Gaian-human is separated from Gaia by hundreds of light-years, that human maintains instantaneous communication with the Gaian world.

It also has limits.

- It was not aware of political changes throughout the galaxy until one of its own, known as the Mule, escaped from Gaia.

**What are Gaia's powers and limits?**

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question?

Answer (score 2):

Let's take your last two points:

> *When a Gaian-human is separated from Gaia by hundreds of light-years, that human maintains instantaneous communication with the Gaian
> world.*

> *It was not aware of political changes throughout the galaxy until one
> of its own, known as the Mule, escaped from Gaia.*

From these, I think it is reasonable to surmise that, for communication/sensing across hyperspatial distances, there needs to be a part of Gaia at 'both ends of the call'.

Presumably, after the Mule's exploits, Gaia sent out agents to various strategic locations throughout the galaxy – notably, to the Two Foundations' HQs on Terminus and Trantor, which led, ultimately, to the summoning of Golan Trevize and Stor Gendibal.

---

Another *significant* limit to Gaia's powers concerns the robot, R. Daneel Olivaw (who was, essentially, the creator of Gaia). Quoting that remarkable robot (from Ch. 101 in *Foundation and Earth*):

> "I can, as an associate of Gaia, make myself aware of what Gaia is
> aware of … Gaia, however, cannot make itself aware of what I am
> aware of … "